Upload file to Azure Blob Storage with Microsoft.XMLHTTP with progres VBA
I’m trying to upload a file to Storage  using Microsoft.XMLHTTP in VBA for MS Access with progress tracking. Uploading without progress tracking works fine, but I need to have progress tracking, especially for larger files.
I have a problem with this line:
 xmlHttp.send fileData

err: The parameter is incorrect…
I tried to divide the file into 5 portions and upload them, but I am doing something wrong.
Here is the snippet:
 Public Sub UploadToAzureBlob(filePath As String, fileName As String)
    Dim adoStream As Object
    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim responseStatus As Long
    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim fileSize As Long
    Dim bytesSent As Long
    Dim chunkSize As Long
    Dim fileData() As Byte
    Dim progressForm As Form
    Dim numParts As Long

    'On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    filePath = filePath & fileName
    fileName = "/" & URLEncodeJScript(fileName) ' For Azure in this format
    sUrl = blobUrl & fileName & sasToken

    Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    adoStream.Mode = 3
    adoStream.Type = 1
    adoStream.Open
    adoStream.LoadFromFile filePath
 
    fileSize = adoStream.Size
  
    numParts = 5
    chunkSize = fileSize \ numParts
    If chunkSize = 0 Then chunkSize = fileSize

    DoCmd.OpenForm "dlgPRGBAR"
    Set progressForm = Forms!dlgPRGBAR
    
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    bytesSent = 0
    Do While bytesSent < fileSize
        If bytesSent + chunkSize > fileSize Then
            chunkSize = fileSize - bytesSent
        End If
        
        adoStream.Position = bytesSent
        ReDim fileData(0 To chunkSize - 1)
        fileData = adoStream.Read(chunkSize)
        
        Debug.Print "Chunk size: " & chunkSize & " Bytes sent: " & bytesSent

        xmlHttp.Open "PUT", sUrl, False
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob"
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", CStr(chunkSize)
  
        Debug.Print "URL: " & sUrl
        Debug.Print "Content-Length: " & CStr(chunkSize)
        
        xmlHttp.send fileData

        If xmlHttp.status <> 201 And xmlHttp.status <> 202 Then
            Debug.Print "Error: " & xmlHttp.status & " - " & xmlHttp.StatusText
            MsgBox "Error: " & xmlHttp.status & " - " & xmlHttp.StatusText, vbCritical
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
        
        bytesSent = bytesSent + chunkSize
        
        Dim IntValue As Long
        IntValue = (bytesSent \ chunkSize)
        If IntValue >= 5 Then
            IntValue = 5
        End If
        Set prg = Forms!dlgPRGBAR!CtlProgress.Object
        Set Complete = Forms!dlgPRGBAR!lblComplete
        prg.Max = numParts
        prg.Value = IntValue
        
        strComplete = Format((prg.Value / prg.Max) * 100, "##") & " % Complete"
        Complete.Caption = strComplete
        DoCmd.RepaintObject
    Loop

    adoStream.Close
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "dlgPRGBAR"
    
    responseStatus = xmlHttp.status
    If responseStatus = 201 Then
        MsgBox "File uploaded successfully!", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: " & responseStatus & " - " & xmlHttp.StatusText, vbCritical
    End If
    
CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not adoStream Is Nothing Then adoStream.Close
    Set adoStream = Nothing
    Set xmlHttp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume CleanUp
End Sub


According to the Azure documentation:
“Partial updates are not supported with Put Blob. To perform a partial update of the content of a block blob, use the Put Block List operation.”
Unfortunately, I was unsuccessful with this method.
In the meantime, I explored using the Append Blob operation and successfully managed to partially upload a file. While this approach works, I'm unsure if it's the correct method to use, especially regarding incorporating a progress bar during the file upload.
Therefore, I would like to clarify the appropriate way to perform partial uploads to Azure. Should I use the Put Block List operation, or is it acceptable to use the Append Blob operation?
Below is a snippet demonstrating the use of the Append Blob operation;
Note: The new appending blob must be created as a new entry in the container;
It cannot overwrite any existing blob;
 Public Sub UploadToAzureAppendBlob(fileName As String, filePath As String)
    Dim adoStream As Object
    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim responseStatus As Long
    Dim blockSize As Long
    Dim totalSize As Long
    Dim uploadedSize As Long
    Dim chunkSize As Long
    Dim chunkData As Variant
    Dim progressPercent As Integer
    Dim progressForm As Form
    Dim numParts As Integer
    Dim prg As progressBar
    Dim fileSize As Long
    Dim Complete As Label
    
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    adoStream.Type = 1
    adoStream.Open
    adoStream.LoadFromFile filePath
    
    fileSize = adoStream.Size
    uploadedSize = 0

    Select Case fileSize
        Case Is < CLng(512) * CLng(1024)
            numParts = 2
        Case Is < CLng(1) * CLng(1024) * CLng(1024)
            numParts = 3
        Case Else
            numParts = 4
    End Select
    
    chunkSize = fileSize \ numParts
    If chunkSize = 0 Then chunkSize = fileSize

    ' Check if the blob already exists
    sUrl = BLOBURL & "/" & fileName & "?" & sasToken
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    With xmlHttp
        .Open "HEAD", sUrl, False
        .send
        responseStatus = .status
    End With
    
    ' If blob exists, delete it before uploading a new one
    If responseStatus = 200 Then
        
        If MsgBox("File Exists !!!" & vbCrLf & "Do you want to delete it?", vbInformation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "INFO") = vbNo Then
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
        
        ' Blob exists, delete it
        Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        With xmlHttp
            .Open "DELETE", sUrl, False
            .send
            responseStatus = .status
        End With
        
        If responseStatus <> 202 Then
            MsgBox "Error deleting existing blob: " & responseStatus, vbCritical
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenForm "dlgPRGBAR"
    Set progressForm = Forms!dlgPRGBAR
    Set prg = progressForm!CtlProgress.Object
    Set Complete = progressForm!lblComplete
    
    Complete.Caption = "Starting upload..."
    prg.Max = 100
    prg.Value = 10
    DoCmd.RepaintObject
    DoEvents
        
    sUrl = BLOBURL & "/" & URLEncodeJScript(fileName) & "?" & sasToken
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    With xmlHttp
        .Open "PUT", sUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "x-ms-blob-type", "AppendBlob" ' Important: Specify the blob type
        .send ""
        responseStatus = .status
    End With
    
    If responseStatus <> 201 Then
        MsgBox "Error creating append blob: " & responseStatus, vbCritical
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If

    Do While uploadedSize < fileSize

        If uploadedSize + chunkSize > fileSize Then
            chunkSize = fileSize - uploadedSize
        End If
        
        adoStream.Position = uploadedSize
        chunkData = adoStream.Read(chunkSize)

        sUrl = BLOBURL & "/" & URLEncodeJScript(fileName) & "?comp=appendblock&" & sasToken
        Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        With xmlHttp
            .Open "PUT", sUrl, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", LenB(chunkData)
            .send chunkData
            responseStatus = .status
        End With

        If responseStatus = 201 Then
            uploadedSize = uploadedSize + LenB(chunkData)
            progressPercent = Int((uploadedSize / fileSize) * 100)
            Debug.Print "Progress: " & progressPercent & "%"
            
            prg.Max = 100
            prg.Value = progressPercent
            
            Complete.Caption = ""
            DoCmd.RepaintObject
            Complete.Caption = progressPercent & " % Complete"
            DoCmd.RepaintObject
        Else
            MsgBox "Error uploading chunk: " & responseStatus, vbCritical
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "File uploaded successfully!", vbInformation

CleanUp:
    If Not adoStream Is Nothing Then adoStream.Close
    Set adoStream = Nothing
    Set xmlHttp = Nothing
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set prg = Nothing
    Set Complete = Nothing
    Set progressForm = Nothing
        
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "dlgPRGBAR"
    Set progressForm = Nothing
        
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print ERR.Number & " - " & ERR.Description & " File Size: " & fileSize
    MsgBox "ERR.Number : " & ERR.Number & " - " & ERR.Description
    Resume CleanUp
    
End Sub 

